# Scala how can I count the number of occurrences in a list

Tags: scala

```
val list = List(1,2,4,2,4,7,3,2,4)
```

I want to implement it like this: `list.count(2)` (returns 3).

Comment: I don't know if there is a proper way to get the size of a list in scala, but for your situation, you could use a sequence.

Comment: Is this question still unanswered? Asking because you might have forgotten to accept one.

Comment: I don't get why xiefei's answer is not accepted and why there are so many over-complicated answers.

Answer (score 179):

A somewhat cleaner version of one of the other answers is:

```
val s = Seq("apple", "oranges", "apple", "banana", "apple", "oranges", "oranges")

s.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size)
```

giving a `Map` with a count for each item in the original sequence:

```
Map(banana -> 1, oranges -> 3, apple -> 3)
```

The question asks how to find the count of a specific item. With this approach, the solution would require mapping the desired element to its count value as follows:

```
s.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size)("apple")
```

Comment: what is "identity"?

Comment: It is the identity function, as discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28407482/what-does-predef-identity-do-in-scala). The function `groupBy` requires a function that it applies to elements so it knows how to group them. An alternative to grouping the strings in the answer by their identities could be, say, grouping by their length (`groupBy(_.size)`) or by their first letter (`groupBy(_.head)`).

Comment: The drawback is that a lot of useless collection (because only the size is needed) are created.

Comment: what if I wanted to define an accumulator map in that expression instead of creating a new map?

Comment: `s.groupBy(identity)` is essentially taking the place of `s.groupBy(word => word)`

Answer (score 147):

scala collections do have `count`: `list.count(_ == 2)`

Answer (score 56):

I had the same problem as Sharath Prabhal, and I got another (to me clearer) solution :

```
val s = Seq("apple", "oranges", "apple", "banana", "apple", "oranges", "oranges")
s.groupBy(l => l).map(t => (t._1, t._2.length))
```

With as result :

```
Map(banana -> 1, oranges -> 3, apple -> 3)
```

Comment: A somewhat cleaner version is `s.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size)`

Comment: @ohruunuruus this ought to be an answer (vs comment); i would love to enthusiastically upvote, if it were (and select it as the best answer if i were the OP);

Comment: @doug somewhat new to SO and wasn't sure, but happy to oblige

Answer (score 32):

```
list.groupBy(i=>i).mapValues(_.size)
```

gives

```
Map[Int, Int] = Map(1 -> 1, 2 -> 3, 7 -> 1, 3 -> 1, 4 -> 3)
```

Note that you can replace `(i=>i)` with built in `identity` function:

```
list.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size)
```

Comment: love short solutions using built-in libraries

Answer (score 31):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, the [groupMapReduce](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#groupMapReduce[K,B](key:A=%3EK)(f:A=%3EB)(reduce:(B,B)=%3EB):scala.collection.immutable.Map[K,B]) method does that in one pass through the list:

```
// val seq = Seq("apple", "oranges", "apple", "banana", "apple", "oranges", "oranges")
seq.groupMapReduce(identity)(_ => 1)(_ + _)
// immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(banana -> 1, oranges -> 3, apple -> 3)
seq.groupMapReduce(identity)(_ => 1)(_ + _)("apple")
// Int = 3
```

This:

- `group`s list elements (group part of **group**MapReduce)
- `map`s each grouped value occurrence to 1 (map part of group**Map**Reduce)
- `reduce`s values within a group of values (`_ + _`) by summing them (reduce part of groupMap**Reduce**).

This is a [one-pass version](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.0-M5/src/library/scala/collection/Iterable.scala#L604) of what can be translated by:

```
seq.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.map(_ => 1).reduce(_ + _))
```

Comment: Nice, this is what I was looking for, I found it sad that even Java streams (which aren't good in some aspects) allow this in a single pass while Scala couldn't.

Answer (score 14):

```
val list = List(1, 2, 4, 2, 4, 7, 3, 2, 4)
// Using the provided count method this would yield the occurrences of each value in the list:
l map(x => l.count(_ == x))

List[Int] = List(1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 3)
// This will yield a list of pairs where the first number is the number from the original list and the second number represents how often the first number occurs in the list:
l map(x => (x, l.count(_ == x)))
// outputs => List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,1), (2,3), (4,3), (2,3), (4,3), (7,1), (3,1), (2,3), (4,3))
```

Comment: but it yields the num. occurrences for each value as many times as the value occurs—seems inefficient and not very useful...

Comment: Wouldn't     l.distinct map(x => (x, l.count(_ == x)))     be more efficient?

Answer (score 10):

I ran into the same problem but wanted to count multiple items in one go..

```
val s = Seq("apple", "oranges", "apple", "banana", "apple", "oranges", "oranges")
s.foldLeft(Map.empty[String, Int]) { (m, x) => m + ((x, m.getOrElse(x, 0) + 1)) }
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(apple -> 3, oranges -> 3, banana -> 1)
```

https://gist.github.com/sharathprabhal/6890475

Comment: perhaps using `Stream` and the accepted answer will yield your goal of "one go" plus clearer code.

Comment: This solution iterates the List just one time, using groupBy and then map will do it twice.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to use it like `list.count(2)` you have to implement it using an [Implicit Class](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/implicit-classes.html).

```
implicit class Count[T](list: List[T]) {
  def count(n: T): Int = list.count(_ == n)
}

List(1,2,4,2,4,7,3,2,4).count(2)  // returns 3
List(1,2,4,2,4,7,3,2,4).count(5)  // returns 0
```

Answer (score 6):

It is interesting to note that the map with default 0 value, intentionally designed for this case demonstrates the worst performance (and not as concise as `groupBy`)

```
    type Word = String
    type Sentence = Seq[Word]
    type Occurrences = scala.collection.Map[Char, Int]

  def woGrouped(w: Word): Occurrences = {
        w.groupBy(c => c).map({case (c, list) => (c -> list.length)})
  }                                               //> woGrouped: (w: forcomp.threadBug.Word)forcomp.threadBug.Occurrences

  def woGetElse0Map(w: Word): Occurrences = {
        val map = Map[Char, Int]()
        w.foldLeft(map)((m, c) => m + (c -> (m.getOrElse(c, 0) + 1)) )
  }                                               //> woGetElse0Map: (w: forcomp.threadBug.Word)forcomp.threadBug.Occurrences

  def woDeflt0Map(w: Word): Occurrences = {
        val map = Map[Char, Int]().withDefaultValue(0)
        w.foldLeft(map)((m, c) => m + (c -> (m(c) + 1)) )
  }                                               //> woDeflt0Map: (w: forcomp.threadBug.Word)forcomp.threadBug.Occurrences

  def dfltHashMap(w: Word): Occurrences = {
        val map = scala.collection.immutable.HashMap[Char, Int]().withDefaultValue(0)
        w.foldLeft(map)((m, c) => m + (c -> (m(c) + 1)) )
    }                                             //> dfltHashMap: (w: forcomp.threadBug.Word)forcomp.threadBug.Occurrences

    def mmDef(w: Word): Occurrences = {
        val map = scala.collection.mutable.Map[Char, Int]().withDefaultValue(0)
        w.foldLeft(map)((m, c) => m += (c -> (m(c) + 1)) )
  }                                               //> mmDef: (w: forcomp.threadBug.Word)forcomp.threadBug.Occurrences

    val functions = List("grp" -> woGrouped _, "mtbl" -> mmDef _, "else" -> woGetElse0Map _
    , "dfl0" -> woDeflt0Map _, "hash" -> dfltHashMap _
    )                                  //> functions  : List[(String, String => scala.collection.Map[Char,Int])] = Lis
                                                  //| t((grp,<function1>), (mtbl,<function1>), (else,<function1>), (dfl0,<functio
                                                  //| n1>), (hash,<function1>))


    val len = 100 * 1000                      //> len  : Int = 100000
    def test(len: Int) {
        val data: String = scala.util.Random.alphanumeric.take(len).toList.mkString
        val firstResult = functions.head._2(data)

        def run(f: Word => Occurrences): Int = {
            val time1 = System.currentTimeMillis()
            val result= f(data)
            val time2 = (System.currentTimeMillis() - time1)
            assert(result.toSet == firstResult.toSet)
            time2.toInt
        }

        def log(results: Seq[Int]) = {
                 ((functions zip results) map {case ((title, _), r) => title + " " + r} mkString " , ")
        }

        var groupResults = List.fill(functions.length)(1)

        val integrals = for (i <- (1 to 10)) yield {
            val results = functions map (f => (1 to 33).foldLeft(0) ((acc,_) => run(f._2)))
            println (log (results))
                groupResults = (results zip groupResults) map {case (r, gr) => r + gr}
                log(groupResults).toUpperCase
        }

        integrals foreach println

    }                                         //> test: (len: Int)Unit


    test(len)
    test(len * 2)
// GRP 14 , mtbl 11 , else 31 , dfl0 36 , hash 34
// GRP 91 , MTBL 111

    println("Done")
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
    }
```

produces

```
grp 5 , mtbl 5 , else 13 , dfl0 17 , hash 17
grp 3 , mtbl 6 , else 14 , dfl0 16 , hash 16
grp 3 , mtbl 6 , else 13 , dfl0 17 , hash 15
grp 4 , mtbl 5 , else 13 , dfl0 15 , hash 16
grp 23 , mtbl 6 , else 14 , dfl0 15 , hash 16
grp 5 , mtbl 5 , else 13 , dfl0 16 , hash 17
grp 4 , mtbl 6 , else 13 , dfl0 16 , hash 16
grp 4 , mtbl 6 , else 13 , dfl0 17 , hash 15
grp 3 , mtbl 5 , else 14 , dfl0 16 , hash 16
grp 3 , mtbl 6 , else 14 , dfl0 16 , hash 16
GRP 5 , MTBL 5 , ELSE 13 , DFL0 17 , HASH 17
GRP 8 , MTBL 11 , ELSE 27 , DFL0 33 , HASH 33
GRP 11 , MTBL 17 , ELSE 40 , DFL0 50 , HASH 48
GRP 15 , MTBL 22 , ELSE 53 , DFL0 65 , HASH 64
GRP 38 , MTBL 28 , ELSE 67 , DFL0 80 , HASH 80
GRP 43 , MTBL 33 , ELSE 80 , DFL0 96 , HASH 97
GRP 47 , MTBL 39 , ELSE 93 , DFL0 112 , HASH 113
GRP 51 , MTBL 45 , ELSE 106 , DFL0 129 , HASH 128
GRP 54 , MTBL 50 , ELSE 120 , DFL0 145 , HASH 144
GRP 57 , MTBL 56 , ELSE 134 , DFL0 161 , HASH 160
grp 7 , mtbl 11 , else 28 , dfl0 31 , hash 31
grp 7 , mtbl 10 , else 28 , dfl0 32 , hash 31
grp 7 , mtbl 11 , else 28 , dfl0 31 , hash 32
grp 7 , mtbl 11 , else 28 , dfl0 31 , hash 33
grp 7 , mtbl 11 , else 28 , dfl0 32 , hash 31
grp 8 , mtbl 11 , else 28 , dfl0 31 , hash 33
grp 8 , mtbl 11 , else 29 , dfl0 38 , hash 35
grp 7 , mtbl 11 , else 28 , dfl0 32 , hash 33
grp 8 , mtbl 11 , else 32 , dfl0 35 , hash 41
grp 7 , mtbl 13 , else 28 , dfl0 33 , hash 35
GRP 7 , MTBL 11 , ELSE 28 , DFL0 31 , HASH 31
GRP 14 , MTBL 21 , ELSE 56 , DFL0 63 , HASH 62
GRP 21 , MTBL 32 , ELSE 84 , DFL0 94 , HASH 94
GRP 28 , MTBL 43 , ELSE 112 , DFL0 125 , HASH 127
GRP 35 , MTBL 54 , ELSE 140 , DFL0 157 , HASH 158
GRP 43 , MTBL 65 , ELSE 168 , DFL0 188 , HASH 191
GRP 51 , MTBL 76 , ELSE 197 , DFL0 226 , HASH 226
GRP 58 , MTBL 87 , ELSE 225 , DFL0 258 , HASH 259
GRP 66 , MTBL 98 , ELSE 257 , DFL0 293 , HASH 300
GRP 73 , MTBL 111 , ELSE 285 , DFL0 326 , HASH 335
Done
```

It is curious that most concise `groupBy` is faster than even mutable map!

Comment: I'm a little suspicious of this benchmark as it's not clear what the size of the data is. The `groupBy` solution performs a `toLower` but the others do not.  Also why use a pattern match for the map - just use `mapValues`.  So roll that together and you get `def woGrouped(w: Word): Map[Char, Int] = w.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size)` - try that and check the performance for various size lists.  Finally in the other solutions, why a) declare `map` and b) make it a var?? Just do `w.foldLeft(Map.empty[Char, Int])...`

Comment: Thanks for providing more data (changed my vote :). I think the reason why is the implementation of groupBy uses a mutable map of `Builder`s which are optimized for iterative increments. It then converts the mutable map to an immutable using a `MapBuilder`. There is probably some lazy evaluation going on under the hood too to make things faster.

Comment: @samthebest You just lookup the counter and increment it. I do not see what can be cached there. The cache needs to be a map of the same kind anyway.

Comment: I'm not saying it caches anything. I imagine the performance increase comes from the use of `Builder`s, and possibly some lazy evaluation.

Comment: @samthebest lazy evaluation = delayed evaluation (call by name) + caching. You cannot speak about lazy evaluation but not caching.

Answer (score 6):

**Short answer:**

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._
xs.foldMap(x => Map(x -> 1))
```

**Long answer:**

Using [Scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz), given.

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

val xs = List('a, 'b, 'c, 'c, 'a, 'a, 'b, 'd)
```

then all of these (in the order of less simplified to more simplified)

```
xs.map(x => Map(x -> 1)).foldMap(identity)
xs.map(x => Map(x -> 1)).foldMap()
xs.map(x => Map(x -> 1)).suml
xs.map(_ -> 1).foldMap(Map(_))
xs.foldMap(x => Map(x -> 1))
```

yield

```
Map('b -> 2, 'a -> 3, 'c -> 2, 'd -> 1)
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this, should work.

---

```
val list = List(1,2,4,2,4,7,3,2,4)
list.count(_==2)
```

It will return 3

Comment: How does this differ from the answer by xiefei given seven years ago?

Answer (score 4):

I did not get the size of the list using `length` but rather `size` as one the answer above suggested it because of the issue reported [here](https://github.com/scala/collection-strawman/issues/146).

```
val list = List("apple", "oranges", "apple", "banana", "apple", "oranges", "oranges")
list.groupBy(x=>x).map(t => (t._1, t._2.size))
```

Answer (score 4):

using [cats](https://typelevel.org/cats/)

```
import cats.implicits._

"Alphabet".toLowerCase().map(c => Map(c -> 1)).toList.combineAll
"Alphabet".toLowerCase().map(c => Map(c -> 1)).toList.foldMap(identity)
```

Comment: Wow, 4 iterations through the original sequence! Even `seq.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size)` only goes through twice.

Comment: Number of iterations may not matter for a small string like "Alphabet", but when dealing with millions of items in a collection, iterations certainly _do_ matter!

Answer (score 3):

Here is another option:

```
scala> val list = List(1,2,4,2,4,7,3,2,4)
list: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 4, 2, 4, 7, 3, 2, 4)

scala> list.groupBy(x => x) map { case (k,v) => k-> v.length }
res74: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 1, 2 -> 3, 7 -> 1, 3 -> 1, 4 -> 3)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
scala> val list = List(1,2,4,2,4,7,3,2,4)
list: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 4, 2, 4, 7, 3, 2, 4)

scala> println(list.filter(_ == 2).size)
3
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a pretty easy way to do it.

```scala
val data = List("it", "was", "the", "best", "of", "times", "it", "was", 
                 "the", "worst", "of", "times")
data.foldLeft(Map[String,Int]().withDefaultValue(0)){
  case (acc, letter) =>
    acc + (letter -> (1 + acc(letter)))
}
// => Map(worst -> 1, best -> 1, it -> 2, was -> 2, times -> 2, of -> 2, the -> 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val words = Array("Mary", "had", "a", "little", "lamb", "its"
  , "fleece", "was", "white", "as", "snow", "and", "everywhere"
  , "that", "Mary", "went", "the", "lamb", "was", "sure", "to", "go")


words.groupBy(_.length)
```

Comment: How is this answer significantly different from all the other `groupBy()` answers posted so long ago?