# Count occurrences of each element in a List[List[T]] in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Suppose you have

```
val docs = List(List("one", "two"), List("two", "three"))
```

where e.g. List("one", "two") represents a document containing terms "one" and "two", and you want to build a map with the document frequency for every term, i.e. in this case

```
Map("one" -> 1, "two" -> 2, "three" -> 1)
```

How would you do that in Scala? (And in an efficient way, assuming a much larger dataset.)

My first Java-like thought is to use a mutable map:

```
val freqs = mutable.Map.empty[String,Int]
for (doc <- docs)
  for (term <- doc)
    freqs(term) = freqs.getOrElse(term, 0) + 1
```

which works well enough but I'm wondering how you could do that in a more "functional" way, without resorting to a mutable map?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
docs.flatten.foldLeft(new Map.WithDefault(Map[String,Int](),Function.const(0))){
  (m,x) => m + (x -> (1 + m(x)))}
```

What a train wreck!

[Edit]

Ah, that's better!

```
docs.flatten.foldLeft(Map[String,Int]() withDefaultValue 0){
  (m,x) => m + (x -> (1 + m(x)))}
```

Comment: You can shorten the map initialization:  `docs.flatten.foldLeft( Map[String,Int]() withDefaultValue 0 ){ (m,x) => ... }`

Comment: It does seem faster than `groupBy`, so marking this as accepted. But both answers are interesting.

Answer (score 20):

Try this:

```
scala> docs.flatten.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size)
res0: Map[String,Int] = Map(one -> 1, two -> 2, three -> 1)
```

If you are going to be accessing the counts many times, then you should avoid `mapValues` since it is "lazy" and, thus, would recompute the size on every access.  This version gives you the same result but won't require the recomputations:

```
docs.flatten.groupBy(identity).map(x => (x._1, x._2.size))
```

The `identity` function just means `x => x`.

Comment: Nice. It does seem slower than with a mutable map though, with just ~10k terms. Cost of transforming collections 3 times?

Comment: Yeah, it's nice and functional, but copying all that data around isn't helping the efficiency.  The mutable Map version doesn't waste a lot of time.

Comment: +1 for teaching me that `mapValues` recomputes the map at each traversal. But in that case a expression with `foldLeft` should perform better than `groubBy`.

Comment: Perfect answer.  According to my benchmarking for my use case this vs a manual mutable map implementation is actually up to 4x faster.  Speed is important for my use as this sits inside a mapreduce job processing TB of data.  Furthermore as the Scala compiler and JVM get better over time this will auto optimize, whereas manual implementations will not.

Comment: @samthebest I wonder why people concerned of performance systematically choose this solution instead of foldLeft of map with default value, which was intentionally designed for this problem. Performance figures undoubtfully demonstrate that maps outperform the groupBy http://stackoverflow.com/a/24723417/1083704.

Comment: @Val "undoubtfully"? Well I just checked `l.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size)` against `l.foldLeft(Map.empty[Int, Int].withDefaultValue(0))((m, x) => m + (x -> (1 + m(x))))` where `l` is `(1 to 10000).map(_ => scala.util.Random.nextInt(100)).toList`. With 5000 trials the `groupBy` approach took 2510 ms, whereas the `foldLeft` approach took 8349 ms.  I've repeated this experiment with many other distributions, and different machines.  Anyway, if you actually look at the implementation of `groupBy` you'll see why :)

Answer (score 0):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, after `flatten`ing the list of lists, we can use [`groupMapReduce`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#groupMapReduce[K,B](key:A=%3EK)(f:A=%3EB)(reduce:(B,B)=%3EB):scala.collection.immutable.Map[K,B]) which is a one-pass alternative to `groupBy`/`mapValues`:

```
// val docs = List(List("one", "two"), List("two", "three"))
docs.flatten.groupMapReduce(identity)(_ => 1)(_ + _)
// Map[String,Int] = Map("one" -> 1, "three" -> 1, "two" -> 2)
```

This:

- `flatten`s the `List` of `List`s as a `List`
- `group`s list elements (`identity`) (group part of **group**MapReduce)
- `map`s each grouped value occurrence to 1 (`_ => 1`) (map part of group**Map**Reduce)
- `reduce`s values within a group of values (`_ + _`) by summing them (reduce part of groupMap**Reduce**).