# Create Map holding a # of appearance for each List element

Tags: scala, collections

I'm new to Scala.

If I have the following `List`:

```
val ls = List("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c")
```

how can I create a `Map` that holds an number of appearances for every element in the list?

For example the `Map` for the list above should be:

```
Map("a" -> 3, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 1)
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448685/scala-how-can-i-count-the-number-of-occurrences-in-a-list - search for "count frequency" or "count occurrence".

Comment: the solutions there seem iterate over the collection multiple times, and don't yield a `Map`; in fact, they yield, imho, quite a useless result, in addition to being inefficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
list.foldLeft(Map[String, Int]() withDefaultValue 0) { (m, x) => m + (x -> (m(x) + 1)) }
```

snippet in action:

```
scala> val list = List("a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "a")
list: List[String] = List(a, a, b, c, c, a)

scala> list.foldLeft(Map[String, Int]() withDefaultValue 0) { (m, x) => m + (x -> (1 + m(x))) }
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(a -> 3, b -> 1, c -> 2)
```

(directly based on [Count occurrences of each element in a List[List[T]] in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166317/count-occurrences-of-each-element-in-a-listlistt-in-scala))

Comment: Wow, Can you please elaborate on this example? if "Map[String, Int]() withDefaultValue 0" means that the Empty Map will be our Initial Value in foldLeft, what would be the meaning of { (m, x) => m + (x -> (m(x) + 1)) }?

Comment: Assuming you know how `foldLeft` works in general, the expression you're asking about is taking taking the accumulated map and adding or updating a key in it; it's an immutable `Map` so you don't update it but you create a new one by adding key-value pairs to it. Anyway, just look into `foldLeft`—it's a very common "pattern" in functional programming :)

Comment: ...oh and it works because of the `withDefaultValue 0` part so you don't have to check if a value has already been seen before because the `Map` just returns `0` by default if the key doesn't exist; e.g. `(Map[String, Int]() withDefaultValue 0)("foo")` gives `0` instead of throwing an exception.

Answer (score 2):

Not as efficient as Erik's `foldLeft` solution:

```
val ls = List("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c")
ls.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size)
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(a -> 3, c -> 1, b -> 2)
```

Comment: `.map { case (x, xs) => x -> xs.size }` would look nicer :)

Comment: Agreed :) updated answer

Comment: Actually, the other thread uses `.mapValues(_.size)`, which is much shorter and avoids the `.toMap` also.

Answer (score 2):

With [scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz),

```
xs foldMap (x => Map(x -> 1))
```

Comment: Nice to know; but gotta be a bit more into funprog than average to appreciate or perhaps even understand this one :)