# get method of hashmap is not returning null

Tags: scala

This line : `var counter : Integer = jm.get(ls)` in below code returns an Integer of value 0 when it should be null. Why is this occuring ?

According to the documentation the get method of HashMap returns null if the element is not found. The code below is counting the number of elements in a list

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

object Tester {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {


    var listOfLinks : java.util.Set[String] = new java.util.TreeSet[String]
    listOfLinks.add("1")
    listOfLinks.add("1")
    listOfLinks.add("1")
    listOfLinks.add("2")
    listOfLinks.add("3")
    listOfLinks.add("3")
    listOfLinks.add("3")
    listOfLinks.add("3")

    var l: java.util.List[String] = new java.util.ArrayList[String]
    var jm: java.util.Map[String, Int] = new java.util.HashMap[String, Int];

    for (ls <- listOfLinks) {
      var counter : Integer = jm.get(ls)
      if (counter == null) {
        jm.put(ls, 1)
      } else {
        counter = counter + 1
        jm.put(ls, counter)
      }
    }

    for(jmv <- jm){
      println(jmv._1+" , "+jmv._2)
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: That's just a conjecture, but I *think* that the default value of `Int` in Scala is 0, not `null`. Even `null.asInstanceOf[Int]` gives `0`. So when the value is not found, `null` changes to `0`...

Comment: It is not directly related with your question, but if you need to count the occurrences of items in a list have a look at [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448685/scala-how-can-i-count-the-number-of-occurrences-in-a-list)

Comment: Above code, even if I use `Int` instead of `String` in `jm`, it still works. `jm.get(1)` returns me `0`. How is jm taking Int when it is a HashMap of String, Int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 var jm: java.util.Map[String, Int] = new java.util.HashMap[String, Int];
```

Here in the Map interface you are using key as **String** the value is ***Int***. So ***Int*** default value is the 0.

```
    var counter : Integer = jm.get(ls)
```

So here counter can hold only 0 value because in the counter variable value come not Key.

```
  jm.get(ls);
```

Answer (score 1):

In Scala, `Int` is the `AnyVal` type(kind of primitive). It cannot be null.