# What does Predef.identity do in scala?

Tags: scala

[Here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Predef$) is documentation about `Predef`, but there is no word about identity. What is this function used for? And what it does?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's just an instance of the [identity function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_function), predefined for convenience, and perhaps to prevent people from redefining it on their own a whole bunch of times. `identity` simply returns its argument. It can be handy sometimes to pass to higher-order functions. You could do something like:

```
scala> def squareIf(test: Boolean) = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).map(if (test) x => x * x else identity) 
squareIf: (test: Boolean)List[Int]

scala> squareIf(true)
res4: List[Int] = List(1, 4, 9, 16, 25)

scala> squareIf(false)
res5: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

I've also seen it used as a default argument value at times. Obviously, you could just say `x => x` any place you might use `identity`, and you'd even save a couple characters, so it doesn't buy you much, but it can be self-documenting.

Answer (score 6):

Besides what [acjay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/807674/acjay) have already mentioned, Identity function is extremely useful in conjunction with implicit parameters.

Suppose you have some function like this:

```
implicit def foo[B](b: B)(implicit converter: B => A) = ...
```

In this case, Identity function will be used as an implicit converter when some instance of B <: A is passed as a function first argument.

If you are not familiar with implicit conversions and how to use implicit parameters to chain them, read this: http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/chaining-implicits.html

Comment: fantastic tip for the common data converter pattern