# Reverse a word-frequency map in Scala

Tags: scala, flatmap

I have a word-frequency array like this:

```
[("hello", 1), ("world", 5), ("globle", 1)]
```

I have to `reverse` it such that I get frequency-to-wordCount map like this:
    [(1, 2), (5, 1)]

Notice that since two words ("hello" and "globe") have the frequency 1, the value of the `reversed` mapping is `2`. However, since there is only one word with a frequency `5`, so, the value of that entry is `1`. How can I do this in scala?

Update:

I happened to figure this out as well:

```
arr.groupBy(_._2).map(x => (x._1,x._2.toList.length))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala how can I count the number of occurrences in a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448685/scala-how-can-i-count-the-number-of-occurrences-in-a-list)

Comment: You don't need `.toList` since the `x._2` collection already has a `length` method.

Answer (score 4):

You can first group by the count, and then just get the size of each group

```
val frequencies = List(("hello", 1), ("world", 5), ("globle", 1))
val reversed = frequencies.groupBy(_._2).mapValues(_.size).toList
res0: List[(Int, Int)] = List((5,1), (1,2))
```

Comment: thanks. I happened to figure out an alternate answer as well. Updating my original post with that too. thank you.