# Scala: Find the most frequent X string in a list of strings

Tags: scala

What I am trying to do is find the most frequent substring of a given length, through a list of strings. So far, I've only come up with the signature of the function:

```
def getFreqSub(lst: List[String], k: Int)
```

For the sake of simplicity, I say that k will always be smaller than the max char size of each string in the list, so I dont have to do that check. I have found some documentation on this, but to no avail. I thought of using the substring function, but how will that work in order to check every, lets say for k=2, combination of letters? Any help/hint/link is appreciated.

**Example: I have this list ("Hello","Heyo","Hel") and the output should be "He" for k = 2, "Hel" for k = 3**

Comment: `lst.filter(_.length==k).???` then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448685/scala-how-can-i-count-the-number-of-occurrences-in-a-list

Comment: @Paul i get this error when i try to use the (identity) thing:

found   : Int => Int
 required: String => ?
       d.groupBy(identity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't very efficient, but it works and is simple to follow:

```
object q42456681 {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {

    assert(getFreqSub(List("Hello","Heyo","Hel"), 2) == "He")
    assert(getFreqSub(List("Hello","Heyo","Hel"), 3) == "Hel")
  }

  def getFreqSub(lst: List[String], k: Int): String = {
    val allSubstrsOfDesiredLen =
      lst.flatMap { str =>
        (0 to (str.length - k)).map { startIdx =>
          str.substring(startIdx, startIdx + k)
        }
      }

    allSubstrsOfDesiredLen
      .groupBy(identity)
      .mapValues(_.length)
      .maxBy(_._2)
      ._1
  }
}
```

If you have a long list of strings to search, you will need to spend time optimising it. It would be more efficient to use an imperative approach and construct a hash or tree map of substrings to count as the search progresses. (@prayagupd's answer shows how to do this)

Comment: let me give it a try, thanks for the clear response in advance!

Comment: I get this error: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int => Int
 required: String => ?
             .groupBy(identity)

I run it on Eclipse SCALA IDE, Scala Interpreter (console) Am I supposed to run it somewhere else? Sorry for the dumb questions, I am new.

Comment: try  replacing `identity` with `(s)=>s`

Comment: yeah, it works now. Accepted. Can you give me some hints as to where to look for some good scala tutorials? I had no luck so far.

Comment: The "Programming in Scala" book by Odersky et al. is the best Scala learning resource I know of.  GL

Comment: Reading the Scala API, e.g. [List](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/#scala.collection.immutable.List).  There is a also a great coursera course "Functional Programming Principles in Scala by Martin Odersky".  Remarkably, you'll be seeing generics and covariance in the first course of the series.

Answer (score 3):

Very traditional answer :)

- use a `HashMap` to index each substring of given length k and its occurance
- sort to get the substring that is most frequent :)

// algorithm

```
  def getFreqSub(list: List[String], k: Int): (String, Int) = {
    val index = scala.collection.mutable.Map.empty[String, Int]

    list.foreach { input =>
      for (substring <- input.sliding(k)) { // alternative to .substring(i, i + windowSize)
           index(substring) = index.getOrElse(substring, 0) + 1
      }
    }

   index.toMap.toSeq.sortBy(_._1).head
  }
```

//Tests

```
val twoLetters = getFreqSub(List("Hello", "Heyo", "Hel"), 2)
assert(twoLetters._1 == "He")
assert(twoLetters._2 == 3) //occurance

val threeLetters= getFreqSub(List("Hello", "Heyo", "Hel"), 3)
assert(threeLetters._1 == "Hel")
assert(threeLetters._2 == 2) //occurance
```

### Note on IterableLike#sliding

returns an iterator of given sliding window.

```
val string = "HELLO"
val window = 2
string.sliding(window).foreach { substring =>
  println(substring)
}
```

output

```
HE
EL
LL
LO
```

Comment: This is more efficient than my answer; nice

Comment: Nice one!  Also, you can replace the generator with `sliding`: for (substring <- input.sliding(k)) { index(substring) = index.getOrElse(substring, 0) + 1} :)

Comment: @AndreiT. you are right, sliding is sexier :) Thanks for pointing that out.