# scala: find the amount of a specific element in a list

Tags: scala

I want to write a function `count: (List[Int]) => Int` in scala which counts the amount of a specific element in a list. I want to implement it this way:

```
count(2, List(2, 4, 5, 2, 2, 7))
```

should return 3. How can I do this in scala?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala how can I count the number of occurrences in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448685/scala-how-can-i-count-the-number-of-occurrences-in-a-list)

Comment: With the help of @Jeffrey answer you can use this generic function `def count[T](n : T, list:List[T]) = {list.count(_==n) }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List has an inbuilt count already like @Jeffery mentioned.

You asked to make it a function, so:

```
scala> val count = (x: Int, ls: List[Int]) => ls.count(_ == x)
count: (Int, List[Int]) => Int = <function2>

scala> count(2, List(2,4,5,2,2,7))
res1: Int = 3
```