# Scala: Frequency of characters in a list

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am a novice programmer from a python/java background, who is trying to get to grips with functional programming in scala.
I am trying to write a function that will take a list of characters and return a list of their frequencies. For example, List('a','b','a') should return List(('a', 2), ('b', 1)). 
I am new to scala and tail recursion, so please don't presume much prior knowledge :) Here is what I have:

```
def times(chars: List[Char]): List[(Char, Int)] = {

  def loop(chars: List[Char], list: List[(Char, Int)]): List[(Char, Int)] =
  {
    if (chars.isEmpty) list
    else
    {
      val head = chars.head
      val freq = chars.count(x=> x == head)
      (head,freq) :: list
      loop(chars.tail.filterNot(x=> x == head),list)
    }
  }
  loop(chars,List())
}
```

If I run times(List('a','b','a')) I just get an empty list. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Might be helpful: [Solution using `groupBy` and `mapValues`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448685/scala-how-can-i-count-the-number-of-occurrences-in-a-list): `chars.groupBy(identity).map(_.size)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`List` is immutable so

```
(head, freq) :: list
```

creates a new `List` with `(head, freq)` at the front of that list (because `List` is immutable, however, it's safe for the tail of the new list to be the same object as `list`).  Because you don't assign the new list to anything, that line may as well not happen.

Something like:

```
val nextList = (head, freq) :: list
loop(chars.tail.filterNot(x => x == head), nextList)
```

will result in the list getting built up in `loop`.

Answer (score 1):

While the accepted answer is good enough for the question; some addition for learning::
while processing List items you can/should take advantage of pattern matching like below

```
def loop(chars:List[Char], list:List[(Char,Int)]):List:[(Char,Int)]= chars match{
case head::tail => val freq = chars.count(x=> x == head)
loop(tail.filterNot(x=> x == head), (head, freq)::list)
case Nil => list
}
```