# Scala - grouping and sorting based on condition

Tags: scala

I have this string input ::

> Bob didn't want a hair cut. At the salon, Bob did a bob while getting a bob cut.

I need to do a word count and then sort the output based on the count using Scala. And while the count is same for some words, i need to do a dictionary sorting for the words having same count.

The output should look like ::

> bob    : 4
>
> a  : 3
>
> cut    : 2
>
> at : 1
>
> did    : 1
>
> didn't : 1
>
> getting    : 1
>
> hair   : 1
>
> salon  : 1
>
> the    : 1
>
> want   : 1
>
> while  : 1

I have been able to do the sorting based on word count but couldnt do the sorting based on letters.

I have used this code::

```
import scala.collection.immutable.ListMap

object wordCount {
  def main (args : Array[String]) : Unit ={
    var sentence : String = """Bob didn't want a hair cut. At the 
    salon, 
    Bob did a bob while getting a bob cut."""



var lines = sentence.replaceAll("""[\p{Punct}&&[^']]""", "")

val words = lines.split(" ").map(a => a.toLowerCase())

var word = words.to[Array]

//count.foreach(println)

var varMap : scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, Int]  = scala.collection.mutable.Map()

var b : String = ""

for (b <- words){
  if(varMap.contains(b)){
    var value = varMap(b)
    varMap.remove(b)
    varMap(b) = value+1
  }
  else{
    varMap +=(b ->1)
  }
} 

//var a = ListMap(varMap.toSeq.sortBy(_._2):_*)

var bbq = ListMap(varMap.toSeq.sortWith(_._2 > _._2):_*)

//println(a.getClass)

for ((k,v) <- bbq) println(""+ k+"\t"+": "+v)



//count.foreach(println)



//var words = word.flatMap(line => line.split(" ")).map(a => a.toLowerCase()).map(word => (word,1)).reduceByKey(_+_)
```

}
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
val string: String = "Bob didn't want a hair cut. At the salon, Bob did a bob while getting a bob cut."

val words: List[String] = string.toLowerCase.split("[ .,!?\"]").toList.filterNot(_.isEmpty)
val freqMap: List[(String, Int)] = words.groupBy(w => w).mapValues(_.size).toList

def comparator(tup1: (String, Int), tup2: (String, Int)): Boolean = {
  if (tup1._2 == tup2._2) tup1._1 <= tup2._1
  else tup1._2 > tup2._2
}

val myAnswer: List[(String, Int)] = freqMap.sortWith(comparator)
```

---

Reference links

- [Count the number of occurrences in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448685/scala-how-can-i-count-the-number-of-occurrences-in-a-list)
- [Sort Scala map by Key or Value](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-sort-map-in-scala-key-value-sortby-sortwith)